# How do I get all dates of a given month in a flutter list?

Tags: date, flutter, dart

I'd like to know how I could get all dates of a given month and year added into a Dynamic List in flutter?

The idea is to display this information in a data table.

How can I put all dates (for a given month) in a List?

```
List myListOfDates = Dates(may2020).format(day.month.year)
```

How can I produce this?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand your situation right, what I have stipulated is to find all the dates of the particular specified month.

**ALGORITHM**

1. Take the input in a month number and year, and pass it inside DateTime()
2. Find the total days of the month provided
3. Generate all the dates till the total days we got form the STEP 1
4. print to check

Before we proceed to the code, you might want to check this out, this will help you understand the situation better and clear:

- [DateTime class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/DateTime-class.html)
- [List.generate](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.17.1/dart-core/List/List.generate.html)

**CODE:** It doesn't require any imports, so follow along.

```
void main() {
  // Take the input year, month number, and pass it inside DateTime()
  var now = DateTime(2020, 7);
  
  // Getting the total number of days of the month
  var totalDays = daysInMonth(now);
  
  // Stroing all the dates till the last date
  // since we have found the last date using generate
  var listOfDates = new List<int>.generate(totalDays, (i) => i + 1);
  print(listOfDates);
}

// this returns the last date of the month using DateTime
int daysInMonth(DateTime date){
  var firstDayThisMonth = new DateTime(date.year, date.month, date.day);
  var firstDayNextMonth = new DateTime(firstDayThisMonth.year, firstDayThisMonth.month + 1, firstDayThisMonth.day);
  return firstDayNextMonth.difference(firstDayThisMonth).inDays;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
// since we used month 7, in the DateTime(), so it returned 31, which will give output
// till last date of the specified month
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]
```

**IMPROVEMENT**

If you want to store the data in this format, `dd/mm/yyyy`. We can always modify it. It can be done like this, with a little improvements in the code

```
// make sure you define you List<String> not List<int> in the previous code
// also, in place of May and 2020, you can add your input params for month and year, make sure to convert the numeric month to word format like 7 => July
// like "${i+1} $month, $year"
// I have used my words only
var listOfDates = new List<String>.generate(lastDateOfMonth, (i) => "${i+1}/July/2020");
print(listOfDates);
```

You can also, store the data in whatever form you like, I liked `date/month/year`

**OUTPUT**

```
[1/July/2020, 2/July/2020, 3/July/2020, 4/July/2020, 5/July/2020, 6/July/2020, 7/July/2020, 8/July/2020, 9/July/2020, 10/July/2020, 11/July/2020, 12/July/2020, 13/July/2020, 14/July/2020, 15/July/2020, 16/July/2020, 17/July/2020, 18/July/2020, 19/July/2020, 20/July/2020, 21/July/2020, 22/July/2020, 23/July/2020, 24/July/2020, 25/July/2020, 26/July/2020, 27/July/2020, 28/July/2020, 29/July/2020, 30/July/2020, 31/July/2020]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your last sentence hit the nail on the head: Happy Learning. I'm not at your level, and I'm not sure I totally understand your code.. but I will play with it

Comment: Hahaha! Hey @houba, don't ever think about levels and all. Every body work at their own pace, and reaches to their pinnacle. I am no different, just a learner, who is learning by this too. Play with it. You will be there too. If you find this useful, I would be happy to see it upvoted and marked as correct. Happy learning once again and All the very best :) **Also, look at the newly added section in my answer that is IMPROVEMENT**. It would be useful for you :)

Comment: I got the solution playing around with vars. But I give this 100% points because a) taught me how to think, b) date_utils and dart 2.8.X are incompatible

Comment: Thanks @houba, I am really happy to see you learn! All the best. :) Even I learnt about this incompatibility via you, thank you very much.

Comment: Hey @Alok, how to get date with weekdays also

Answer (score 0):

First, we will need this [date_util](https://pub.dev/packages/date_util) package to obtain the number of days in a month.

Second, we will need this [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package to obtain the DateTime formate.

You can try it through the following code:

> import 'package:date_util/date_util.dart';

> import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

```
     @override
     void initState() {
      final daysCount = DateUtil().daysInMonth(DateTime.may, 2020);
      List<String> days = [];
      for (int i = 1; i < daysCount+1; i++) {
      days.add(DateFormat(DateFormat.YEAR_MONTH_DAY)
          .format(DateTime(2020, DateTime.may, i)));
      }
     super.initState();
     }
```

you can change **DateFormat.YEAR_MONTH_DAY** to any thing you need

This is an image of the output

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This would have been perfect, but it didn't work for me as apparently this pub.dev is only valid for dart < 2.8.x