# Flutter how to show current date and next 5 day dates?

Tags: flutter

I need to show current date and month Also next 5 days date and month in a text widget.

Simply like this

```
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Text('09'),
                      Text('Nov')
                    ],
                  )
```

I need to show in a row that today date or month and the next 5 days date and month. Any guide in code how can i do this thing?

Expected output is

```
28NOV, 29NOV, 30NOV, 1Dec, 2Dec
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63058039/how-do-i-get-all-dates-of-a-given-month-in-a-flutter-list

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes its showing just a date in whole month. I just need next 5 days and month also. Like if today is 28nov and their is december also in next 5 days . so i need date and also  month

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple example. No styles applied, adjust to your needs.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class MyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyScreenState createState() => _MyScreenState();
}

class _MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> {
  final _currentDate = DateTime.now();
  final _dayFormatter = DateFormat('d');
  final _monthFormatter = DateFormat('MMM');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final dates = <Widget>[];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      final date = _currentDate.add(Duration(days: i));
      dates.add(Column(
        children: [
          Text(_dayFormatter.format(date)),
          Text(_monthFormatter.format(date)),
        ],
      ));
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Tests'),
      ),
      body: Row(
        children: dates.map((widget) => Expanded(child: widget)).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also the default month names from the intl library are used.
You might need to adjust the code for i18n.

Answer (score 0):

```
List months = ['jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec'];

DateTime today = DateTime.now();
var currentDate = today.day;
var monthOfCurrentDate = months[today.month +1];

DateTime futureDate = DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 5));
var dayOfFutureDate = futureDate.day;
var monthOfFutureDate = months[futureDate.month+1];
```

You can use like this,

```
   Column(
        children: [
              Text(currentDate.toString()),
              Text(monthOfCurrentDate)
         ],
   )
```

and you can format time as below, using flutter intl package [intl package on pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/intl)

```
DateFormat.MMMd().format(today) // this will output as "17 Nov"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rajitha. i think it's showing currenDate only in text I need to show the current date and moth also next 5 days. So i am expecting output like 27 NOV, 28, Nov, 29,Nov, 30,Nov, 1 December. How can I show something like this?